# Finding incorrect YAML headers

Tags: grep, yaml

I am trying to identify which files in my project have incorrect headers. The files all starts like this

```
---
header:
.
.
.
title: 
some header:
.
.
.
more headers:
level: 
.
.
.
---
```

Where . . . only represents more headers. The headers contains no indentation. Using the following expression I have been able to extract the YAML header from every file.

```
grep -Przo --include=\*.md "^---(.|\n)*?---" .
```

Now I want to list the incorrect YAML headers.

- Every YAML header must have a `title: some text`
- Every YAML header must have `language: [a-z]{2}`
- It must either contain a `external: .*` or `author: .*`.
- The placement of `title:`, `level:`, `external:` and `language:` varies.

I tried to do something like

```
grep -L --include=\*.md -e "external: .*" -e "author: .* ."
```

However the problem with this is that it searches the entire file, not just the YAML header. So I guess solving the issues above boils down to how I can feed the YAML header result from my previous search into grep again. I tried

```
grep -Przo --include=\*.md "^---(.|\n)*?---" . | xargs -0 grep "title:";
```

However this gave me an error "No such file or directory", so I am a bit uncertain how to proceed.

Examples:

```
---
title: Rull-en-ball
level: 1
author: Transkribert og oversatt fra [Unity3D](http://unity3d.com)
translator: Bjørn Fjukstad
license: Oversatt fra [unity3d.com](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/roll-ball-tutorial)
language: nb
---
```

Correct YAML, has an author, language and title.

```
---
title: Mini Golf
level: 2
language: en
external: http://appinventor.mit.edu/explore/ai2/minigolf.html
---
```

Correct YAML, has a title, language, and external instead of author.

```
---
title: 'Stjerner og galakser'
level: 2
logo: ../../assets/img/ccuk_logo.png
license: '[Code Club World Limited Terms of Service](https://github.com/CodeClub/scratch-curriculum/blob/master/LICENSE.md)'
translator: 'Ole Andreas Ramsdal'
language: nb
---
```

Incorrect YAML header, missing author.

Comment: Could you replace the `. . .` with actual data, including "correct" headers as well as "incorrect" headers, so that we know when a solution is working as intended?

Comment: Also, the yaml I've seen (for Ansible) has indentation; does yours?

Comment: @JeffSchaller, no indentation. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way to do it. I assume you have bash (to loop recursively through the files), sed, and awk. Instead of using bash, you could alternatively use `find` with `-exec` to search for the files.

The general flow is:

1. ask bash for the list of `*.md` files, recursively
2. pass each file to `sed` to extract the YAML header
3. pass that YAML header to awk for validation
4. if the header fails validation, print the filename

The script:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s globstar

for file in **/*.md
do
  # use sed for the header
  sed -n /^---$/,/^---$/p "$file" |
  awk '
        BEGIN {
                good_title=0
                good_lang=0
                good_extaut=0
        }
        /^title: .*/             { good_title=1  }
        /^language: [a-z][a-z]$/ { good_lang=1   }
        /^author: .*/            { good_extaut=1 }
        /^external: .*/          { good_extaut=1 }
        END {
                if (good_title && good_lang && good_extaut)
                        exit 0
                else
                        exit 1
        }
        '  \
  || printf "Incorrect header found in %s\n" "$file"
done
```

You can easily adjust the regex matching patterns in the awk script to be stricter or looser, depending on your exact requirements (perhaps you want alphanumeric characters instead of "any", as the current `.` in your example has).

The `sed` statement extracts the YAML header by:

- suppressing default-printing (`-n`)
- asking for a line of addresses that match the pattern: beginning of line, `---`, end of line; the second pattern must occur after the first pattern.
- that range of addresses is then `p`rinted

The `awk` script is a little over-built, but I wanted to spell it out for clarity. Each time awk is called, it sets three flag variables to zero or false. If we see lines that match our criteria, we set the corresponding flag to one/true. Once all the lines have been seen, we return success or failure based on the status of those flags -- they must all be true in order to "pass" validation.

With these appropriately-named sample files scattered into the current directory and a subdirectory:

```
$ tree .
.
├── bad1.md
├── good1.md
├── good2.md
└── subdir
    ├── bad1.md
    └── good1.md

1 directory, 5 files
```

... the script outputs:

```
Incorrect header found in bad1.md
Incorrect header found in subdir/bad1.md
```

Answer (score 0):

To extract the header of a file, we may use `sed` like so:

```bash
sed -e '1,/^---$/!d' -e '/^---$/d' filename
```

This removes everything from the file apart from the lines between line 1 and the next line that is exactly `---`.  The second expression additionally deletes all `---` lines from the data so that you are left with only the YAML header.

I will use the Python-based `yq` utility [from Andrey Kislyuk](https://kislyuk.github.io/yq/).  Since this is a handy wrapper around the versatile JSON parser `jq`, we may easily detect whether the values corresponding to the keys are `null`, non-`null`, or a particular string, etc.

In the `jq` syntax, we may test whether a key, `keyname`, exists in an object with `has("keyname")`. We may also test whether the value of a key matches a particular regular expression, `RE`, using `.keyname | test("RE")`.

The tests that are mentioned in the question could be translated into the following `jq` expression:

```
has("title")            and
(.title | test("."))    and
has("language")         and
(.language | test("[a-z]{2}"))  and
(has("external") or has("author"))
```

or, shorter but less expressive,

```
(.title? != null) and
(.language? | test("[a-z]{2}")) and
(has("external") or has("author"))
```

This ensures that each key exists and that the values for the keys that need to have non-`null` values are correct.

Running this on the three example files, with our tests in the script file `validate`:

```bash
$ sed -e '1,/^---$/!d' -e '/^---$/d' file1.md | yq -f validate
true
$ sed -e '1,/^---$/!d' -e '/^---$/d' file2.md | yq -f validate
true
$ sed -e '1,/^---$/!d' -e '/^---$/d' file3.md | yq -f validate
false
```

We may generalize this to test all the `.md` files in the current directory or below using `find` like so:

```bash
find . -name '*.md' -type f -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        if ! sed -e "1,/^---\$/!d" -e "/^---\$/d" "$pathname" |
             yq -e -f validate >/dev/null
        then
            printf "Invalid YAML header: %s\n" "$pathname"
        fi
    done' sh {} +
```

or, with any shell that supports the `**` globbing pattern (enabled with `shopt -s globstar` in `bash`):

```bash
for pathname in ./**/*.md
do
    if ! sed -e '1,/^---$/!d' -e '/^---$/d' "$pathname" |
         yq -e -f validate >/dev/null
    then
        printf 'Invalid YAML header: %s\n' "$pathname"
    fi
done
```

Here, we additionally throw away the output from `yq` and instead use the tool with its `-e` option.  This makes the exit status of the utility reflect the value of the last evaluated expression, i.e., zero for *true*, and non-zero for *false* in this case.  This makes it easy to use our `sed`+`yq` pipeline directly in an `if` statement.

Running this with our three test files, we get

```
Invalid YAML header: ./file3.md
```